# Connecting to a WiFi via terminal: Error: connection activation failed : No suitable device found for this connection

Tags: command-line, wireless

I am facing difficulty in connecting to a WiFi through terminal . Whichever WiFi I try to connect to using nmcli  the error I get is "connection activation failed : No suitable device found for this connection" 
I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: what is the exact command you are giving? and what is the output of `nmcli device show`

Comment: if you observe 3rd pharagraph.. wifi is unavailable.. something wrong with wifi adapter..

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: what is happening if you are trying to connect via GUI?

Comment: I am unable to login to my account because of Nvidia graphics installation problem. , Now I need to install new drivers but there is no internet connection .

Comment: Ok try using this command `nmcli device wifi connect <yourssid> password <known-password> ifname w101` read the output from 3rd pharagrah and use which is correct one wl01 or w101

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).